# How to add 24 Hours to a date/time field?Can anyone help?

Tags: validation-rule, datetime

I am working on developing a validation rule, where a particular date time field should not be greater than 24 Hours from the Created Date time.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way

```
IF(ISNEW() , NOT(ISBLANK( Field__c ) ) && ROUND((Field__c - Now())*24 ,0) >24, NOT(ISBLANK( Field__c ) ) && ROUND((Field__c - CreatedDate)*24 ,0) > 24 )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Howeverver the provided formula didn't work as expected. Record once saved could not be modified.

Comment: Could you please explain further what you mean by "Record once saved could not be modified." do you mean existing data?

Comment: ROUND( Field__c - CreatedDate ,0) > 0     in the mentioned rule, the field 'CreatedDate' is generated once the record is created but when the same record is editted, it shows error against saving the same as it validates the mentioned rule. Solution?

Comment: Updated description and answer please try this 

Comment: It is not working as expected. Instead of 24 Hours it is validating for 12 hours post the creation date/time.

Comment: try the formula and also please note that now is based on user local setting and not org setting so if the user local is set to Uk Now() would be the UK time..  make a not of these: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324878&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Abhijith - The ask is that the custom date fields should not be greater than 24 hrs.. What you are suggesting is totally different.

@SauravGuha please try the below and replace the custom field with yours 

AND (
NOT(ISBLANK( testDate__c ) ), (testDate__c > CreatedDate + 1440/60)
)

Comment: @Raj - Maybe, I am still missing something but this formula is working for me.... . The null check you have included is required I missed that in one I wrote...  Could you please help me understand??

Comment: @AbhijithE i remember i saw something else in your answer before, your updated formula seems to be working as well but a simple formula like mine should do which shall prevent the user from entering the date greater than 24hrs. 

one mistake in my formula though is, it is adding 24 days instead which i was dumb as f. Saurav can replace 1440/60 to just 1 and should be good. Dont need such a complex validation rule for checking if the date is greater than 24hrs or no. As well, thanks for downvoting :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply... agreed!! and yeah I missed *24 which I have added after the comment...

Comment: Thanks for the genuine help  @AbhijithE, but the Syntax shows an error for  Extra "IF", when removed it is showing other errors. I am an absolute noob, can you please guide me, how to proceed?

Comment: I used the formula as: IF(ISNEW() , NOT(ISBLANK( Date1__c ) ) && ROUND((Date1__c - Now())*24 ,0) >24, NOT(ISBLANK( Date1__c ) ) && ROUND((Date1__c - CreatedDate)*24 ,0) > 24 ) in validation rule it worked for me (ofcourse with some offset) you can also try @Raj's suggestion (I am not sure if it would cause issues during creation as created date would still be null ) I have not tried it from my end....